# Binding Viewmodel Property to dropdown selected item in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

```
public class State
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{

    public State State { get; set; }

}

public class JobSeeker
{

    public Address CurrentAddress { get; set; }


}

public class RegisterVM
{
    public JobSeeker JobSeeker { get; set; }
    public List<State> AllStates { get; set; }
}
```

in Razor

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.JobSeeker.CurrentAddress.State, 
              new SelectList(Model.AllStates, "Id", "Name" ), "  -----Select List-----  ")
```

The result is the drop down is populated with the value present in AllStates, **but the problem is m.JobSeeker.CurrentAddress.State is null when posted to controller action. How to set the selected value of dropdown to property m.JobSeeker.CurrentAddress.State**

Comment: What does the controller look like?

Comment: `State` is a complex object and a `<select>` posts back a single value, not a complex object. It would need to be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.JobSeeker.CurrentAddress.State.ID, ....)` But do not do that!. Add a `public Guid SelectedStata { get; set; }` property to `RegisterVM` and bind to that.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the ViewModel to...

```
public class RegisterVM
{
    public JobSeeker JobSeeker { get; set; }
    public List<State> AllStates { get; set; }
    public string SelectedState { get; set; }
}
```

..and have the Drop down use the `SelectedState` property instead...

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedState, 
              new SelectList(Model.AllStates, "Id", "Name" ), "  -----Select List-----  ")
```

You should then be able to assign it to the `State` by name.

Comment: Based on OP's `State` class, it would need to be `public Guid SelectedState { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

How is the model binder supposed to map an Id of the state to the model of type State??? If you change your razor view code to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.JobSeeker.CurrentAddress.State.Id, new SelectList(Model.AllStates, "Id", "Name" ), "--Select--")
```

Then you will get a non-null instance of state but only the Id property will be populated...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you. I was able to figure out the problem after viewing the Request.Form object which has only one value against State Field i.e SelectedValue of dropdownlist.
As far I understand, it is not possible to set the state property from UI hence I have to use the selected ID of State received from view in the ModelBinder or Controller to set the State Object from db .